# Implementing play! json read/write for type parametric class

Tags: json, scala, types, playframework-2.0

i'm dealing with the following:

```
>>> A.scala 
abstract class A[T <: A[T]](field:String){
   def ~>(a : T):Boolean
}
<<<<

>>> B.scala
case class B(field:String,field1:String) extends A[B](field){
  override def ~>(other: B): Boolean = 
   field == other.field && field1 == other.field1
}
object B{

 implicit object BFormat extends Format[B] {

  override def reads(json:JsValue):JsResult[B] = JsSuccess(new B(
    (json \ "pathTo" \ "field").as[String],
    (json \ "pathTo" \ "field1).as[String]
  ))
  override def writes(b:B):JsValue = Json.obj(
    "field" -> b.field,
    "field1" -> b.field1
  )

 }

 def simpleB = new B("foo","bar")
}
<<<<
```

The parameter `T` in the superclass `A` is used (indirectly) in the method `~>` that performs a match between **this** and the other object which must be of the same type. It works but
now i want to write read/write format combinators of Play Framework! 2.2.2 json library for the class `A` but i'm stuck because i don't know how to implement that, using a companion object i couldn't annotate type parameters (in the companion object) and even if i extend `Format[A[T]]` i don't know how to implement

```
implicit def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A[T]]
implicit def writes(o: A[T]): JsValue
```

I already know the subclasses of `A`, they are two and already implements read/writes for json but i am not able to do so for the superclass `A` which has a type parameter (of which i know i can use json read/writes), any clue?

Example and error:

```
def getMyA[T <: A[T]](json:JsValue):Option[T] =
 (json \ "mypath").asOpt[T]

 diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[T] starting with method GenericFormat in trait DefaultFormat
```

thanks

Comment: `reads` and `writes` should not be marked `implicit`, the `Format` itself should be. Your `reads` method is going to need to determine which class to instantiate based on the JSON. The `writes` method should delegate to the `Writes` you have made for the subclasses. How are you using the type parameter? In you minimal example it serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Well, i can remove the 'implicit' modifier from the methods but i can't put it on the abstract class since it's a top level object, if i use it to extends `Format[A[T]]`. I know what to do with `reads`and `writes`but it's rather difficult, i should do a match on the type `T` and use the underlying json combinator of the subclass B or C.I am writing an extended example in the post to make clear the purpose of the type parameter